# Are there any perk based RPG systems (e.g. Fallout III, Skyrim, etc)?

Tags: game-recommendation

The title pretty much says it.  I have been tooling around with the concept of a pen and paper RPG that uses a Perk based system.  I feel that a perk based system would give the flexibility of a point-buy but not grant the min/max aspects normally associated with them.

I did a google search and didn't find much.  If any of you know of a system like this, please let me.

**Things I am looking for:**

- Not class based
- Strength gained from levelling is primarily based on feats/perks, not on 'stats'.
- System for magic would be a bonus

Genre/setting isn't important, I mostly just want to look at it and see what they did and how they used it.  Also, any experience/insight on a system you know of might be helpful too.  Thank you.

Comment: Perks are basically Feats which are incredibly common in RPG systems, specifically D&D and D&D-esque games.

Comment: Indeed, there's a massive variety of systems that use something similar, and in order to meet the requirements for a question for this site, I'm afraid you're going to have to narrow things down significantly in terms of what you are looking for

Comment: I'm looking for a system that doesn't have classes like D&D.

Comment: @DimensionsGaming There’s still literally thousands of potential answers to this question. We need more information about what *else* you are looking for from this system, since we can’t list thousands of systems, and you offer no guidance on how to trim that down. If we ran with this question, it would turn into a pure popularity contest, and that’s not what we’re about.

Comment: Lots and lots, even without classes. [See this page about the size of the RPG field](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-just-dont-understand-the-scope-of-the-rpg-lands) and [this one about why we can't just start listing off as many as we can think of](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/whats-so-problematic-about-a-recommendation-question-having-potentially-hundred). If you can narrow this question down so that the set of RPGs that qualify as answers becomes small, we might be able to help.

Comment: Alright, I apologize.  Because I was having so much trouble finding one, I didn't realize there were that many out there.  I am specifically looking for something similar to how the Fallout and Skyrim video games are set up.  I want something that does not have classes, but your character is built up as you buy perks/feats/etc as you level up.  Something that includes magic would be great.  If that is still too vague, just give me some of the most popular ones that are more well known.  If that doesn't work then I guess I'll just go back to google.

Comment: No need to apologise! Closing has more to do with keeping the site on topic (and our topic is unusually tightly-defined) not punishment for transgression, and since we have strong tools for that, we don't have any need to make cranky faces at you. :) This isn't even a bad question, just one that doesn't fit the site's purpose (since ["every answer is equally valid"](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)). You could ask it on a [forum](http://forum.rpg.net) and be gladly received; or poke around and earn some rep so you can join our [chat] and ask there.

Comment: I have added this meta question about a possibly better way to handle questions like this. http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5431/how-do-we-handle-game-survey-questions

Comment: @DimensionsGaming - System recommendation questions are hard.  There's definitely games out there that match what you're looking for - you just need to narrow it down more.  Your last comment is a good start.  Take a look at [this FAQ](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-on-topic) and see if there's any more detail you can add.  Does theme matter? (Cyberpunk, classic fantasy, real life, space, wild west, ...)  Do you prefer detailed combat or abstract? Are levels even important? (There's games where characters are *only* composed of "perks")

Comment: @Theik Good edit; not good enough, but now we're getting somewhere.